# How can we get a handle on <a> element defined with href="javascript:void(0)"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

There is an element defined as

```
<div class="Meeting">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Hello</a>
</div>
```

I want to obtain a reference of this element in jquery and modify its state.
How to obtain a handle to this element ?

Comment: `jQuery('a')` will do it

Comment: What makes this element unique?

Comment: `$('div.Meeting a').first()` _could_ work, but it depends on the full structure of your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is look at what lets you uniquely identify the element.

For instance, if it's the *only* `a` element that's a child of a `.Meeting` element, then:

```
var a = $(".Meeting > a");
```

Or if it's the only one with `href="javascript:void(0)"`:

```
var a = $(".Meeting > a[href=javascript:void(0)]");
```

And so on. However you would identify that element using CSS, you can use with jQuery. jQuery also provides some CSS extensions (although using them may slow down the performance of the selector, if it's in a place that matters).

You can also use a combination of a CSS selector and any of [jQuery's traversing methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/). For instance, if it's not the only `a` in a `.Meeting` but it *is* always the first, then:

```
var a = $(".Meeting > a").first();
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. All the options are quite informative. last one worked for me. I actually had multiple values. Did not know that rest of the elements would be necessary. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var anchorWithJavascriptVoid = $('a[href="javascript:void(0)"]');
```